# Magento new page template

Tags: templates, magento

I'm trying to add a new template so I can have two content blocks side by side. Ex: content_left and content_right. The problem is that the new fields are empty and I can't get anything to show up in them. The goal is to have the login and account creation side by side, each in there own blocks.

Here is the new template 2columns.phtml (trimmed some):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main1">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content_left') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-main2"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content_right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

Here is XML where I'm trying to use it:

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
        <reference name="content_left">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
       </reference>
        <reference name="content_right">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

Everything seems to work except content_left and content_right. Which, unfortunately, need to show everything important. I've tried to update the CSS and I have it defined in a module. Is the problem using 'content_left/right' instead of just 'content' and something else already used? Please help, I've been all day at this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do:

1. Create the **content_left** and **content_right** blocks instead of referencing them. They don't actually exist anywhere in the layout files, which is why referencing them will not work. This needs to be done before you can add other blocks to them.
2. Ensure the created **content_left** and **content_right** blocks are created in the correct place. By simply changing the reference to a block you would be creating them at the same level as the root block...they won't render if they are placed here. So you need to add them into the root block.

This was the layout I was able to get working:

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2column-contact.phtml</template></action>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content_left" as="content_left" translate="label">
            <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content_right" as="content_right" translate="label">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having this problem is because you need to add a '**block**' not a '**reference**'.

**Block**

This is attached to each template, giving it the necessary functionality to do its job.

**Reference**

This is a way to attach blocks (or other rules) to specific pages (for example, adding a special block to the product view page).

To fix this problem, replace this line:

```
<reference name="content_left">
```

With:

```
<block type="catalog/product" template="path/to/your/template.phtml">
```

If on the hand, your intention is to get everything in the  in to one column - (i.e. you want to output 'customer_form_register', and 'customer.form.register.fields.before' in to one column, and 'customer_form_login' in to another column)

Then do the following:

1) Remove the 2 'references> that you added.

2) Create a div (for each section you want) in the phtml file.

3) Echo out the block names (i.e. customer_form_login) within those div's and add the necessary CSS rules.